# How to display Japanese characters and Chinese characters on Amazon Lightsail wordpress server?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, encoding, character-encoding

I am trying to add a function to our website which can let our clients know their visa application status.
I tried to use python to pull data from monday.com and make into a csv file.
Then I used php to read the csv and do the function.
However because we are based in Japan, we need to use Japanese characters to show the name of our clients. The characters cannot be properly displayed on lightsail(debian linux11). Specifically, the characters cannot be properly displayed when using cat command and when opened using nano or vim. They also cannot be properly displayed on the website as well(I am using a snippet plugin to insert php codes to read a csv file on our server and display the result)

I have tried to install the font and use uft-8 for encoding and decoding, but not working. I have searched for the answer but I cannot find it.
I am not a professional programmer and I know only a little python and php. If anyone can help, I will be very grateful.

I tried installing Japanese fonts and using utf-8 to encode. But nothing worked. I also searched in google, without a satisfying answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be properly displayed"? Displayed in your WordPress web pages? On shells and other apps running on the Lightsail desktop? In a spreadsheet program displaying your .csv file?  Please [edit] your question to provide more detail.